# SBT doesn't seem to find dependencies in ftp repository

Tags: scala, ftp, dependencies, sbt

I'm migrating some java+maven projects to scala+sbt but I've been having some troubles to make sbt work with my maven repository.

I'm using sbt 0.13.5 and my build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "test"

version := "0.0.1"

resolvers += "uqbar-repo" at "ftp://mvn+uqbar-wiki.org:<my_password>@ftp.uqbar-wiki.org/releases"

libraryDependencies += "uqbar" % "uqbar-commons" % "1.1"
```

As you may see, my dependencies are hosted in an ftp server (ssh is not available so just ftp, NOT sftp) and there seems to be no problem to access them from maven, but running sbt yields the following error:

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/nicolas/Dev/test/}test...
[info] Resolving uqbar#uqbar-commons;1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: uqbar#uqbar-commons;1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/nicolas/.ivy2/local/uqbar/uqbar-commons/1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/uqbar/uqbar-commons/1.1/uqbar-commons-1.1.pom
[warn] ==== uqbar-repo: tried
[warn]   ftp://mvn+uqbar-wiki.org:<my_password>@ftp.uqbar-wiki.org/releases/uqbar/uqbar-commons/1.1/uqbar-commons-1.1.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: uqbar#uqbar-commons;1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: uqbar#uqbar-commons;1.1: not found
```

I found this weird, since the files are there (pom can be accessed from the url sbt tried, even from a browser) so I used a sniffer to check what was actually being send and receive. The output I got was:

```
 25 2.887053000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      386    Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
 27 2.887536000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      91     Request: USER mvn+uqbar-wiki.org
 29 3.135330000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      117    Response: 331 User mvn+uqbar-wiki.org OK. Password required
 30 3.135590000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      84     Request: PASS <my_password>
 32 3.424510000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      109    Response: 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
 33 3.424825000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      74     Request: TYPE I
 35 3.665227000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      96     Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
 36 3.665449000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      80     Request: CWD releases
 37 3.897858000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      106    Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /releases
 38 3.898170000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      77     Request: CWD uqbar
 39 4.132531000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      112    Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /releases/uqbar
 40 4.132765000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      85     Request: CWD uqbar-commons
 43 4.365921000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      126    Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /releases/uqbar/uqbar-commons
 44 4.366217000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      75     Request: CWD 1.1
 45 4.606673000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      130    Response: 250 OK. Current directory is /releases/uqbar/uqbar-commons/1.1
 46 4.606921000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      76     Request: EPSV ALL
 47 4.842167000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      87     Response: 500 Unknown command
 48 4.842374000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      72     Request: PASV
 49 5.076465000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      114    Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (31,22,4,33,187,254)
 54 5.309929000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      94     Request: RETR uqbar-commons-1.1.pom
 55 5.547075000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      96     Response: 150 Accepted data connection
 64 5.550301000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      161    Response: 226-File successfully transferred
 66 5.550465000    192.168.1.109         31.22.4.33            FTP      72     Request: QUIT
 69 5.789052000    31.22.4.33            192.168.1.109         FTP      133    Response: 221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 2 kbytes.
```

Now, my ftp is a little rusty, but that log seems to indicate that sbt found and download the pom.

In case it is of any use, here is the pom content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>uqbar</groupId>
<artifactId>uqbar-commons</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>uqbar-commons</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>uqbar</groupId>
    <artifactId>uqbar-parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <scm.svnPath>svn/uqbar/commons/uqbar-commons</scm.svnPath>
</properties>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://uqbar.no-ip.org/svn/uqbar/commons/uqbar-commons/tags/uqbar-commons-1.1</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://uqbar.no-ip.org/svn/uqbar/commons/uqbar-commons/tags/uqbar-commons-1.1</developerConnection>
    <url>http://uqbar.no-ip.org/svn/uqbar/commons/uqbar-commons/tags/uqbar-commons-1.1</url>
</scm>

<dependencies>
    <!-- UQBAR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.uqbar</groupId>
        <artifactId>uqbar-class-descriptor</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uqbar</groupId>
        <artifactId>uqbar-bttf</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- /UQBAR -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I've search the documentation but found nothing and I have no idea where the problem may be, so any hint is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had the same problem, and found that SBT doesn't resolve downloaded poms (at least by default, and I haven't found how to enable it if it is implemented). This is pretty embarassing, in my case it failed even on compilation, saying classes not found, rather than during dependency resolution.